# Why doesn't showing a hidden section work?

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have a section which should be hidden by default, so I have done this:

```
<section id="sction" style="display:none">
    <div class="card">
    </div>
</section>
```

In jQuery, when I press the button, it should show the section, but it doesn't.

```
if($("#btn").click(function(){
     $("#sction").show();
 }));
```

[Demo](https://jsbin.com/woduviqani/edit?html,css,js,output)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The correct display property for a div is **"block"**  instead of **"show"**. You can also simply use `.show()` instead of `.css("display","block")`.

However I don't know why you wrapped the code inside `IF BLOCK` but you have also to wrap it inside `DOM Ready` to initialize the function.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
   if($("#btn").click(function(){
   $("#sction").css("display","block");
   }));
})
```

```css
.card {
    box-shadow: 0 4px 8px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
    transition: 0.3s;
    width: 40%;
    height:350px;
    background-color:black;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body>

<section id="sction" style="display:none">
<div class="card">
</div>
</section>
<button id="btn">
mmmmmmmmm
</button>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: `.show()` also works. make sure wrapped inside DOM ready. @mrslt

Comment: @mrslt To be able use `.show()` you have to set a default `display` css propertie in your CSS. Can't work if you set it in HTML with `style` attribute

Answer (score 0):

Css `display` has four properties none, inline, block, and inline-block.

```js
$("#btn").click(function(){

$("#sction").css("display","block");

});
```

```css
.card {
    box-shadow: 0 4px 8px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
    transition: 0.3s;
    width: 40%;
    height:350px;
    background-color:black;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<section id="sction" style="display:none">
<div class="card">
  <p>holla</p>
</div>
</section>
<button id="btn">
mmmmmmmmm
</button>
```

Answer (score -2):

no if() required
this should work:

```
$("#btn").click(function(){
     $("#sction").show();
 });
```